# spark: convert dataframe to svm labeled point

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

When referring to the spark ml/mllib docs, they all start from a svm stored example. This is really frustrating me since there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to go from a standard RDD[Row] or Dataframe (taken from a "table" select) to this notation without first storing it.

This is just an inconvenience when dealing with 3 features or so, but when you scale that up to lots and lots of features, it's implying you will be doing a lot of typing and searching.

I ended up with something like this: (where "train" is a random split of a dataset w/ features stored in a table)

```
val trainLp = train.map(row => LabeledPoint(row.getInt(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(row(8).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(9).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(10).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(11).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(12).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(13).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(14).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(15).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(18).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(21).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(27).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(28).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(29).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(30).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble,row(31).asInstanceOf[Double],row(32).asInstanceOf[Double],row(33).asInstanceOf[Double],row(34).asInstanceOf[Double],row(35).asInstanceOf[Double],row(36).asInstanceOf[Double],row(37).asInstanceOf[Double],row(38).asInstanceOf[Double],row(39).asInstanceOf[Double],row(40).asInstanceOf[Double],row(41).asInstanceOf[Double],row(42).asInstanceOf[Double],row(43).asInstanceOf[Double])))
```

This is a nightmare to maintain, since these rows tend to change pretty often.

And here I'm only in the stage of getting labeled points, I'm not even at a svm stored version of this data.

What am I missing here that could potentially save me days of misery?

EDIT:

I got one step closer to the solution using something called a [vectorassembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) to build up my vector

Comment: I have exacttly the same frusterating issue, im using pspark

Answer (score -1):

Usually, CSV files are raw, unfiltered sources of information. Often they provide the original source of information.

In order to build a model, you usually want to go through a data cleansing, data preparation, data wrangling (and maybe more "data x" wording) phase before you build your model. This phase usually takes a big piece of the model building, and usually requires exploration of data. Typically, a process of transformation and feature selection (and creation) occurs between the original data and the data that builds the model.

If your CSV files don't need any of these preliminary phases - good for you! 
You can always make configuration files that can keep track of certain columns or column indexes that build your model.

If your DataFrame comes from a "select", I guess what you can do to improve legibility and maintainability is to use column names instead of index numbers.

```
df.select($"my_col_1", $"my_col_2", .. )
```

and then operate through

```
row.getAs[String]("my_col_1")
```